# RequireJs: Use autoloading-deps with shim

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have defined a RequireJs configuration which defines paths and shims:

```
require.config({
    // define application bootstrap
    deps: ["main"],

    // define library shortcuts
    paths: {
        app: "app"
        , jquery: "lib/jquery"
        , underscore: "lib/underscore"
        , backbone: "lib/backbone"
        , bootstrap: "lib/bootstrap"
    },

    // define library dependencies
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: "$"
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: "bootstrap"
        },

        // main application
        app: {
            deps: ["backbone"],
            exports: "App"
        }
    }
});
```

As you see the last "shim" declaration should make it able to access backbone (and it deps) when I load the main App(-namespace).

In reality this doesn't work:

```
require(["app"], function($, _, Backbone, App){
    app.router = new Backbone.Router.extend({
        // routing and route actions
    });
});
```

What makes me wondering is that in the "backbone-boilderplate"-project, Backbone (and its deps) are available this way:
https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.js

The not even had to define this in the function.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to remove the `$, _, Backbone` from the `require`-function where you extend the router. I think that the shims work so that they just export global values that you don't need to add to any calls

Comment: Hey, that works great :) I even can drop the "backbone" keyword in the deps-array of the define function although this doesn't work in every module... Would you create an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `$, _, Backbone`-parameters from the `require`-function where you extend the Router. The shims export global values, so there is no need to reference to them in `require` or `define` calls like you do for regular dependencies.

Passing them as parameters messes with the global variables and most likely results in them being undefined.

Comment: A precision : passing Backbone as a parameter hides the global definition, you could use `window.Backbone` directly

Answer (score 11):

From what I've read, requirejs passes arguments based on what you specify in the array... Thus your call should look like this:

```
require(["app"], function (App) { // less arguments
});
```

Or like this:

```
require(
    ["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "app"], // more deps
    function ($, _, Backbone, App) {
    }
);
```

Comment: I agree as well.  encapsulating dependencies is the whole point of AMD. You should do it this way

Comment: whereas here you have the variables encapsulated, you don't conform the dry principle. Let's say all of the sudden `app` has more dependencies than the ones you listed there.

Comment: this does not even work IMHO. where is guaranteed that jquery is loaded before underscore? or backbone after underscore? Well... it is NOT guaranteed but it is required to be loaded one after another

Comment: If you need the order to be correct you can just give underscore a dep of jquery, backbone a dep of underscore and app a dep of backbone via shim. If you then call app it will check that the other libs are loaded first.  Just call: require(['app'], function (App) { ... }); The rest of the $ and _ vars should be available in the scope of the function.