# Uncaught ReferenceError: myliba is not defined with the simplest realistic requireJS example

Tags: jquery, requirejs

in `main.js`

```
    require.config({
    waitSeconds: 15,
    urlArgs: "version=" + new Date(), //to make sure we have no caching problems during development
    deps: ["main"],
    baseUrl: '../js/',
    paths: {
    "jquery": "jquery-1.11.0",
    "myliba": "myliba"
    },

    shim: {
     "myliba": {
        exports: "myliba",
        deps: ["jquery"]
      },
      "jquery": {
        exports: "$"
      }
    }
    });

require(["myliba"], function () {
    myliba.test();
});
```

in `myliba.js`

```
define("myliba", function () {

            var myliba = {};

            test: function (){
             alert("requireJs is easy to use, it is well worth the hassle");
            }

});
```

results in

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myliba is not defined

if I add an `alert("lovin requirejs");` into `myliba` I very well get the alert, so it gets loaded and evaluated. My define of myliba does not get exported though.

I read [**--->here<---**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389715/requirejs-use-autoloading-deps-with-shim/11397825#11397825) that you cannot declare the arguments within the function call if you do it the shim way.

As far as I am concerned, there is no other clean way other than shim. Just imagine I have:
jquery, jqueryui, myliba, mylibb

myliba depends on jquery

**mylibb depends on jqueryui and myliba which depends on jquery**

I couldn't come up with a clean way other than shim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amd modules are resolved by returning something (string, function, object) at the end.

```
define("myliba", ["jquery"], function ($) {
    return {
        test: function () {
            alert("requireJs is easy to use, it is well worth the hassle");
        }
    };
});
```

**UPD:**

I hope now i understand you correct and this solution will help you:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.11.0',
        jqueryui: 'path/to/jquery-ui'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        jqueryui: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});

define('myliba', ['jquery'], function($) { ... });

define('mylibb', ['myliba', 'jqueryui'], function(myliba, $) { ... });

require(['myliba', 'mylibb'], function(myliba, mylibb) { ... });
```

Comment: that is right. But i am sorry to tell you, that it doesn't work when using shim. And remove the $ sign, this is another mistake

Comment: Why `$` is mistake? It will be passed to arguments if you put `jquery` in dependencies

Comment: read the link in my post. It reads like this: `--->here<--- `

Comment: @Toskan you understand that post wrong. It's says that if you haven't set libs in dependency array than there is no way the will shown in arguments.

Comment: @Toskan but still i can't understand if your lib defined as normal amd module why you need put it in shims if you can set all dependencies as mentioned in answer?

Answer (score -1):

Alright so I saw this in the jQuery file, seems like this is the way it has to be done.

```
// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in
// AMD (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

so

```
define("myliba", function () {

            var myliba = {};

            test: function (){
             alert("requireJs is easy to use, it is well worth the hassle");
            }
     window.myliba = myliba;

});
```

solves the issue

Comment: this is the only way using shim

Comment: If your lib defined as amd module why you may want to use shims? Shims are for non-amd libs